# how to check reference equality in an object which implements content equality?

Tags: java, object, methods

...in other words:
let's suppose I have 2 Strings declared as so:

```
String one = new String("yay!");
String two = new String("yay!");
```

these two Strings are two different objects, but if I run

```
if(one.equals(two))
   System.out.println("equals() returns true.");
```

I get "equals() returns true".
This is because the String class overrides the equals() method to implement a content level equality.
However, I need to access a reference level equality (like the one implemented in Object) to distinguish the object one form the object two.
How can I do that?

I tried this:

```
one.getClass().getSuperclass().equals();
```

to try to invoke the Object equals() method of the String one but it didn't work.

Any advice?

Comment: I don't want to go off topic, but I want to add this information I think it would be useful to the ones who stumbles in this question. My problem was to be able to handle objects implementing content-equality as unique elements. Of course the other side of my problem was to use them inside an HashMap<Object, Object> as key elements. There exist a Map implementation to serve this purpose, the [IdentityHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String` in java uses a `String Literal Pool`, this means is: "When you try construct a string, first String class search in `Literal Pool` for traditional same string ,if exist return it, and if don't exist create it", so you can't check by `equals` method compare refernce of String instance, you have to use `==` operator as following:

```
String one = new String("yay!");
String two = new String("yay!");
if(one.equals(two))
   System.out.println("equals() returns true.");
if(one == two)
   System.out.println(" == operator returns true.");
```

result is :

```
equals() returns true.
```

see following link for more information:

1. http://blog.enrii.com/2006/03/15/java-string-equality-common-mistake/
2. [Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

Comment: This answer fails to define reference equality.  It then mentions the complication with String, but "When you try construct a string,.." is proven wrong by the sample output; and if it was correct "you have to use == operator" would be incorrect.  See the answer by @tom or Wojtek.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to check reference just perform:

```
one == two
```

But be careful with strings.  There is a thing called [String constant pool](http://jimlife.wordpress.com/2007/08/10/java-constant-pool-string/) so they may refer to the same object.

Comment: You're right, but the "constant pool" is a datastructure in class files, the other thing is a *string intern pool*, the technique you refer to is called string interning.

Answer (score 2):

Use simple `==` comparison. However to avoid `String` interning you have to create your Strings using `char` arrays such as: `String me = new String(new char[] { 'm', 'e' });` instead of using String literals `"me"` such as `String me = new String("me");`.

Comment: very good thing to know, thank you. Unfortunately I have no control over the String creation since they are instatiated by JAX2B marshaller form an XML input. Maybe it can be configured to avoid the String interning mechanism, but I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (one == two)
    System.out.println("one and two are the same object");
```

Answer (score 1):

The only this you need is "==" equality operator.